# (Wocommerce Filtering) How can I get a product attribute from the current category?

Tags: php, woocommerce, filter

I want to create filters from specific product attributes, in the current category. The concept is that whenever a user browses a category of products, there will be filters, corresponding to the product attributes that exist in the products of the current category. In the example, when a user browses the category **laptops**, I want a set of filters being displayed, so he can click on them and filter out the results, displaying only the selected products with the specific attribute.

I am now delving into PHP and WooCommerce, so I could not get any results so far. What I have done so far is I tried this code where I only get the specific attribute I want, but for all products, regardless of category. This is working because I get all the values of the attribute I check and I get the correct results when I click on an attribute. I know that there is no "checking for current category" in this code because I don't know how it should be written and have failed multiple times to the correct checking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

```
function filters_cpu( $args = array() ) { 
    $terms = get_terms( 'pa_cpu' );
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($terms as $each_term) {
        echo '<li>';   
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $each_term ) . '">' . $each_term->name . '</a>';
        echo '</li>';   
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the default "Filter By Attribute" widget? 
This one will work as you wanted. This will show the filter widget only if the displayed products have those attributes assigned to them.

I am not sure whether you tried this or not.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/widgets/product-filter-attributes/

Apart from this default option, There is a good free woocommerce Product Filter plugin. You can try this one too.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/

Comment: Thank you for informing me though I am aware of those plugins. I am more into doing it myself.